# HDMI cable lost colors

Tags: pinout, hdmi

I accidentally bent one plug on one side of an HDMI cable and, after taking the
plug apart and straightening everything out as much as possible (after which the
only apparent structural oddity is that pin #18 is shorter than the others, but
I think this pin is not used and the plug has always been like this), the display
no longer shows colors.

Audio is fine.  Video is black and white, but otherwise fine.

I must have some connectivity problem with some of the pins (or even with the outer
ground shield around all pins), but can't find it by wiggling things...it's always
black and white.  What is the most likely problem?

Comment: You can grab a DVM and test continuity on each one of the signals. But I wouldn't bother and just get a new cable.

Comment: I don't have a DVM available and yes, I know the practical solution is just to buy a new cable.  But, this is more curiosity and theory now...what pin affects the color alone?

Comment: Sounds impossible. Which pin did you bend? Which devices are these, PC and monitor, gameconsole and TV? Pin 18 is by definion shorter than others so it makes contact after all other pins, and must be connected as the pin is an important part of HDMI interface. But seriously, throw the cable away and buy a new one, before the plug destroys sowmething expensive like a HDMI socket on video card, game console or TV the next time you plug it in. No pin affects the color alone.

Comment: @Justme All of the pins were bent at about 45 degrees (the entire ground shield sleeve and interior pins were simply bent since the cable was being pulled tight and torqueing the plug about its long axis). Maybe some management pin (which specifies the color protocol) is not connected, so the system defaults to a black and white standard even though the color data itself is available?

Comment: Some pin might be disconnected. There is no pin to select between color and greyscale modes so it might be that the source sends something when it does not recognize the display. But since you don't say what the source or sink was and what HDMI standard these use, so we can't even start guessing what it might be.

Comment: Perfectly possible if the cable is carrying YCrCb video and only the Y part is getting through. But as others have said, don't risk damaging expensive equipment with a damaged cable, it's just not worth it.

Comment: @Finnbarr Not possible. First reason is that the channel that carries Y is not the one that carries the syncs.

Answer (score 1):

tl; dr: Don't waste your time or risk damaging your gear. Get a new cable.

As to why it's behaving that way, one or more of the TMDS pairs isn't making good contact. If your output is Y/Cb/Cr (color difference) then maybe only Y is getting through, resulting in a monochrome display. Or, the monitor expects **both** Cb and Cr, and punts to monochrome if one of those is missing. Or some other reason, depending on the format selected.

Pin 18 is +5V from the source device. It's shorter so that it mates last. This power is used to run the monitor's Display Data Channel (DDC) hardware (an I2C EEPROM or its equivalent), so that the monitor's configuration can be read out without powering on the entire unit. The host uses the DDC info and negotiates a compatible color and resolution setting and starts sending data in that format.

DDC is also used in copy protection. When HDCP-enabled content is being displayed, DDC is active all the time, updating keying material in the monitor periodically. If this handshake fails, the source is obliged to either blank the display, or down-res the content to 480i. Heinous, I know.

So you're partially right in that pin 18 plays a role in color selection: +5V is part of DDC, as well as the I2C pair SCL and SDA. Which seems to be working.

Again, not worth your time or risk. Monoprice or Blue Jeans Cables are your friends. The cables are cheap, even for HDMI 2.1 compliant ones.

Comment: So, can I say that there are 4 TMDS pairs, one of which is the clock signal which must be working for me (for the record, I can change my source to any of the 720p/1080i/1080p options and still my only display problem is the lack of color), and the other 3 are configured to separately provide Y, Cb, and Cr?.  My likely problem is then that one or both of the Cb/Cr pairs have an open circuit.  The important pins are 1-9 (3 pairs plus the ground for each), and just one of these 9 pins being open could therefore cause my problem.

Comment: Yes, basically. I don't remember the YCbCr mapping in 4:2:2 mode, but its, say, CH0 = Y and CH1 = Cb/Cr, having that channel dead would kill color completely.